# Using a variable in a batch script for SQLLDR

Tags: sql, database, oracle, batch-file

Hi i am trying to set a variable in my .bat file and i want to use the variable in sqlldr code to state the file (infile)

This is what i have in my bat file for the variable:

```
set directroy_name= D:\Folder\Folder\Folder\File.csv
```

Then in my command file i have

```
load data
infile '%directory_name%'
```

When ever i try to run the .bat file from the command prompt i just receive the SQL_Loader_500: unable to ope file (%directory_name%.dat

I know the files in the correct location?

any ideas why its doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that - you're expecting the Oracle executable to understand Windows environment variable syntax. If it did that it would have to deal with `$` variables in Unix, etc.

You can just pass the file name on the command line instead. In your control file omit the `INFILE` altogether, then when you call SQL*Loader add a a [`DATA` command-line argument](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16536/ldr_params.htm#SUTIL1023):

```
sqlldr user/password CONTROL=your.ctl DATA=%directory_name% ...
```

Assuming your variable is just oddly named and does have a full file path as you've shown.

If it's present, the [`INFILE` argument will be overridden by the command-line argument](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16536/ldr_control_file.htm#SUTIL1063), so you could include a default fixed value if you wanted to, I suppose.

You also appear to have a typo; you set `directroy_name`, but then use `directory_name`, which will have no value. You need to change that to:

```
set directory_name= D:\Folder\Folder\Folder\File.csv
```

Comment: @RichardC - yes. It doesn't have to be a variable of course, you can just specify the full file path in the `DATA` argument, but I assume it's being used elsewhere in your script. You might want to set the `BAD` file name etc. in the same way.

Comment: thanks for the help. I have edited my sqlldr command:
set directroy_name=D:\filename.csv
sqlldr userid/password@database control= D:\file.sql log= D:\log.log DATA=%directory_name%


in my command file i am getting syntax error now i have remvoed the infile, it reads:
load data
TRUNCATE
into table tablename
fields terminated by ',' TRAILING NULLCOLS
(colm1, coml2)

Comment: When i run the .bat file from the command line i just recieve SQL*LOADER-100: syntax error on command line, does not tell me anything specfic

Comment: And the variable name mismatch? Did you check that? It looks like the var you're actually using will be empty, which would probably explain that error?

Comment: the variables are called the same it is set like this:
set directroy_name=D:\filename.csv
and called and the end of the sqlldr like this:
DATA= %directroy_name%

what do you mean about the variable been empty it should be the .cvs file?

Comment: Hi @AlexPoole, just tried to run the command prompt and its work fine. thanks for the help here